# Android API seekToMillis() explanation needed

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api

I'm using `Google API` for rendering youtube videos. Ißm trying to seek to specific time using `seekToMillis()` but the video starts always from the beginning.

Code:

```
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player, boolean arg2) {
            youTubePlayer = player;
            youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("o7VVHhK9zf0");
            youTubePlayer.seekToMillis(50000);



        }

        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to start the video at a specific position, use this method instead:

`YouTubePlayer.loadVideo(String videoId, int timeMillis)`

[From here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Loads and plays the specified video and the playback will start at the specified time in the video.

Comment: ...some times i overlook simple things like this :/